# Mapping a filesystem without using scandir() or readdir

Tags: php, windows, iis, filesystems

I have a variety of folders and files that I would like to map using PHP.
It's not really and option to store them in the database, they have to be stored on a windows filesystem.

Unfortunately, due to the restrictions of the drive (it is a network drive). I cannot use scandir() and set_include_path() as I get the 'open_basedir restriction in effect' error message. I can't get around this as I have not got access to the security permissions that would allow me to add IIS_IUSR in the security properties.
I should add, I have full read/write access to everything on the drive as a normal user.

I need a tool that will run when it is asked to by PHP rather than something that will run on a schedule.

One way I have considered accomplishing this is to use a service written in C# and have PHP call that when needed. I'm just not sure of a way to glue them together.

If anyone has any better suggestions of how to do this please say.

Comment: How about `opendir` with `readdir` ?

Comment: Can you `exec()`? Also are you running under a web server SAPI or the CLI? Also, what information do you need from the files? Do you need to read the file data, or just get a folder listing? Do you need anything like file size, mod time etc?

Comment: Same restrictions with readdir unfortunately.

Comment: Look into what @BerryLangerak wrote.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a restriction on the paths you can traverse (such as open_basedir), you can't read outside of that directory, so you'll have to use something "external" instead. As you're on Windows and I have little experience left on that OS, I'd go for the simplest solution possible: simply calling the "dir" program. I'm thinking that this might work, but I have no way of testing it, unfortunately:

```
<?php
$output = `dir /s C:\directory\to\traverse`;

var_dump( $output );
```

Comment: Incredible. Isn't this a security issue?

Comment: @pete Depends. If you can actually call exec( ), one would assume that the user PHP is running under is limited anyway. Just perhaps less limited than with the open_basedir restriction. Either way, I don't see this as a security issue in PHP :)

Comment: @BerryLangerak Thanks. I don't know much about Windows security, but it just looked strange.

Comment: `one would assume that the user PHP is running under is limited anyway` - never assume. Especially things like this, many hosting server administrators are idiots. Trust me on that one. It should be noted that it is a limitation of `dir` that the target directory must be accessible as it it were a local directory (i.e. mapped as a network drive) - `\\server\share` UNC paths don't work (even from cmd). Note also that backticks don't work when `shell_exec()` is disabled.

Comment: @DaveRandom Ah, I would assume in the context of a competent server administrator, naturally. If it's not limited, however, it makes it even *easier* to accomplish what he wants to do. If shell_exec is disabled, the only way to get the file listing is calling the server administrator and asking him for a solution ;)

Comment: @DaveRandom the command `dir /s \\10.0.2.15\foo` works on my virtual machine, it seems UNC paths are resolved (on Windows XP, anyway).

Comment: @BerryLangerak So it does. I just tried `\\server` and that doesn't work, but it seems specifying a specific share (`\\server\share`) or one of it's subdirs does. You know, I have been working under that incorrect impression for a very long time. Well, you learn something every day.

Comment: The IIS_IUSR account probably does not have access to the network drive. The OP would have to use something like smbclient and authenticate using his own network credentials. There's no execution bit on Windows, so an EXE file placed alongside the PHP file should work. Putting one's login and password into a script that others might see is sort of crazy though.

Comment: I have tried this command in Windows' command prompt.
`dir /s /b "C:\folder\to\traverse\somefile*.pdf"`
It finds the right files.
But in PHP when I try
`$output = shell_exec("dir /s /b \"C:\folder\to\traverse\somefile*.pdf\"");`
It just returns NULL

Comment: Just tried this again and is working perfectly for my local drive, however it still does not want to map a networked drive, so I think I am going to have to go the windows service root.